# Unsure solution of ODE with DiracDelta function

Tags: differential-equations

Could the following solution be treated as reliable?

```
DSolve[{D[x[t], t] == x[t]^3*DiracDelta[t - 2], x[1] == 1}, x[t], t]
```

> DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution.
>
> {{x[t] -> 1/Sqrt[1 - 2 HeavisideTheta[-2 + t]]}}

I have in mind that the function `x[t]` takes complex values for $ t>2.$

The general solution is produced with no warning:

```
DSolve[D[x[t], t] == x[t]^3*DiracDelta[t - 2], x[t], t]
```

> {{x[t] -> -(1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY8dR.png) - HeavisideTheta[-2 + t]]))},                {x[t] -> 1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY8dR.png) - HeavisideTheta[-2 + t]])}}

Addition. Its numeric solution is quite different:

```
s = NDSolve[{D[x[t], t] == x[t]^3*DiracDelta[t - 2], x[1] == 1},x[t], {t, 1, 3}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 1, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Which one of these solutions is more true?

Comment: In the second, there are two $\pm$ branches; only one takes real values for some `t` when a condition is `x[1] == 1`l that leads to `C[1] == -1/2`. The second solution is empty for this initial condition, and this is what the first message is about. Next, not every differential equation has a solution that is valid on $(-\infty,+\infty)$, and this is just the case here.

Comment: @corey979: Thank you for your interest and feedback. The open question is: where is the obtained solution valid?

Comment: `FunctionDomain[
 1/Sqrt[1 - 2 HeavisideTheta[-2 + t]] /. HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep,
  t]` gives `t < 2`. _Mathematica_ doesn't want to work with `HeavisideTheta` in `FunctionDomain`, hence the replacement to an equivalent `UnitStep`.

Comment: @corey979: I don't see a problem here: HeavisideTheta[1] outputs 1.

Comment: I was explicit enough, but: what does `FunctionDomain[HeavisideTheta[t], t]` output?

Comment: @corey979: It outputs FunctionDomain::nmet: Unable to find the domain with the available methods. So what?

Comment: So, connect this output with my comment ("_Mathematica_ doesn't want to work with `HeavisideTheta` in `FunctionDomain`) and your comment ("I don't see a problem here: HeavisideTheta[1] outputs 1"). It could output even a dragon, but `FunctionDomain` doesn't want to work with it.

Comment: Ad Addition. **Every** piecewise (with regard to $t\lessgtr 2$) constant function is a solution to the ODE: $\delta(t-2)=0$ for $t\neq 2$, and $x'(t)$ of an arbitrary constant is equal to zero. $\delta(t)$ is not a function - it's a distribution, and _common sense_ (i.e., treating it as a function) usually fails. The implementation of `DiracDelta` is connected with `HeavisideTheta` via `HeavisideTheta'[t] == DiracDelta[t]`. The internal algorithms of `DSolve` seem to rely on this relation.

Comment: As per "which solution is more true": they are all correct. It's like asking what is more true - $2+2=4$ or $1+3=4$?

Comment: @corey979.Execute ->`NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t]^3*DiracDelta[t - 2], 
  x[2.00000001] == 2.00000001}, x, {t, -4, 4}, WorkingPrecision -> 5]`->Kernel Crash !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the Mathematica answers in my question are not correct and should be treated as bugs. Here are arguments. Up to Rudin W. Functional Analysis, McGraw-Hill Book Company, NY,…,Toronto, 1973, Part 2, Ch. 6, Par. 6.15, the multiplication  $ f(t)\delta(t)$ is defined if the function $f(t)$ is infinitely differentiable. This implies the solution $x(t)$ must be continuous at $t=2$. Therefore, the only true solution of the ODE with the initial condition under consideration is a constant function $x(t)=1$. This is not only my personal opinion: I consulted my colleagues about this topic. In particular, one may contact [Dr. Yu. Golovatyj](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?option_lang=eng&personid=21928) at yu_holovaty@franko.lviv.ua (with his kind permission) for more details concerning this complex matter under consideration. Wolfram staff also obtained my report [CASE:3789146].

Answer (score 2):

Converting `DiracDelta[t-2]` to `Piecewise[{{DiracDelta[0], t == 2}}]` helps.

```
DSolve[{D[x[t], t] == x[t]^3*Piecewise[{{DiracDelta[0], t == 2}}], x[1] == 1}, x[t], t]

(* {{x[t] -> 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so let me begin.

Mathematica itself does a semi-good job here. It find 2 solutions where one is not applicable for your startingcondition. So it finds the only solution which is

```
1/Sqrt[1 - 2 HeavisideTheta[-2 + t]]
```

But this only seems to work for $t<2$ and this is indeed right (we'll see later).

If we apply the Fourier- or Laplactransform we get what we deserve. (nothing we can work with because the $\delta$-function forces us to know $x(2)$)

$$x(t)=\theta(t-2)\cdot x(2)+C$$
Since 2 is a exact discontinuity we cannot use this.
But we can use the good old approach of seperation of variables so we solve it by hand:
$$\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}=x^3(t)\cdot\delta(t-2)$$
$$\int\frac{1}{x^3(t)}\text{d}x(t)=\int\delta(t-2)\text{d}t$$
$$-\frac{1}{2x^2(t)}=\theta(t-2)+C$$
Now we would like to use $(...)^{-1}$ but this will limit us to the domain of $t>2$ but this is okay, Mathematica solved it already for $t<2$.
We get:
$$x(t)=\pm\sqrt{C-\frac{\theta(t-2)}{2}}$$
with your condition:
$$x(t)=\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{\theta(t-2)}{2}}=const((2<t)\wedge(2>t))$$

So we look into the visualization:

```
Plot[{1/Sqrt[1-2 HeavisideTheta[-2+t]],Sqrt[1-HeavisideTheta[t-2]/2]},{t,-3,3},PlotRange->{{-3,3},{-5,5}},PlotStyle->{{Red},{Blue,Dashed}},PlotLegends->"Expressions"]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Oh look we have won! Our derived expression suprisingly also describes $t<2$.
Let's confirm that:

```
equ=x'[t]==x[t]^3*DiracDelta[t-2];
form=Sqrt[1-HeavisideTheta[t-2]/2];
FullSimplify[equ/.{x[t]->form,x'[t]->D[form,t]},{t\[Element]Reals,t<2}]
FullSimplify[equ/.{x[t]->form,x'[t]->D[form,t]},{t\[Element]Reals,t>2}]
FullSimplify[equ/.{x[t]->form,x'[t]->D[form,t]},{t\[Element]Reals,t==2}]
```

> True
>
> True
>
> -(DiracDelta[0]/(2 Sqrt[4-2 HeavisideTheta[0]]))==DiracDelta[0] (1-HeavisideTheta[0]/2)^(3/2)

Year. Exactly what we expected. Our formula desribes it perfectly EXCEPT in $t=2$.

Comment: Note also [my comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132453/unsure-solution-of-ode-with-diracdelta-function#comment357465_132453), and that $x(t)+c=\int x'(t)dt=\int x^3(t)\delta(t-2)dt=x^3(2)$, hence every piecewise constant function is a solution, e.g. $x(t)=-googol$ for $t<2$ ,and $x(t)=Knuth\, number$ for $t>2$. With the initial condition $x(1)=1$ the part for $t<2$ is $x(t)=1$, but for $t>2$ it still can be any number.

Comment: @JUlien Kluge: Thank you. As it was noticed by corey979,  every piecewise (with regard to t≶2,t≶2) constant function is a solution to the ODE.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica's first (analytic) solution is dead on correct.  It satisfies the differential equation and the boundary condition.  When that is the case, you have the solution.

```
ode = D[x[t], t] == x[t]^3*DiracDelta[t - 2];

DSolve[{ode, x[1] == 1}, x[t], t] // Flatten
(*{x[t] -> 1/Sqrt[1 - 2*HeavisideTheta[t - 2]]}*)

x[t_] = x[t] /. %;
```

MMa thinks it satisfies the ode.

```
ode
(*True*)
```

and the bc

```
x[1]
(*1*)
```

Take the derivative by hand as a check.  write x as

```
(1 - 2 HeavisideTheta[t - 2])^(-1/2)
```

and the derivative

```
(-1/2) (1 - 2 HeavisideTheta[t - 2])^(-3/2) (-2 DiracDelta[t - 2])
(*DiracDelta[t - 2]/(1 - 2*HeavisideTheta[t - 2])^(3/2)*)
```

We used the fact the derivative of the HeavisideTheta is the DiracDelta. 
Look at

```
x[t]^3 DiracDelta[t - 2]
(*DiracDelta[t - 2]/(1 - 2 HeavisideTheta[t - 2])^(3/2)*)

%%==%
(*True*)
```

Plot both real and imaginary parts of the solution

[image]

Looking at the ode, in this case the slope is `0` everywhere except at `x = 2` and the solution matches that, but it does jump from pure real for `x < 2` to pure imaginary for `x > 2`.
And no, x will not be continuous across the delta function.  `f[t]` being continuous does not mean `f[t] δ[t]` is continuous.

The second (numerical) solution appears to be incorrect for values > 2.  Even though numerical, the solution is evidently:

```
xnum[t_] = 1 + HeavisideTheta[t - 2]
```

check

ode /. x -> xnum

```
(*DiracDelta[t - 2] == DiracDelta[t - 2] (HeavisideTheta[t - 2] + 1)^3*)
```

Which in general is not true for all `t`.