# How to deal with a Dirac delta function numerically?

Tags: differential-equations

I need to solve some differential equations with a Dirac delta function. e.g. the source terms are like, $\delta(x)$ and $\partial_x \delta(x)$.

Could I just use the Gaussian type function? e.g.

$$ \delta(x-a) = \frac{a_1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-\frac{(x-a)^2}{a_1}),$$ and,
$$ \partial_x \delta(x-a) = - \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}(x-a)\exp(-\frac{(x-a)^2}{a_1})  $$

where by setting e.g. $a_1=0.01$.

If the answer is yes, then how to choose the reasonable values of $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Thanks!

Comment: While this is an interesting (and hard) question, I think it's more suitable for https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is your $a_2$?

Comment: It really depends on equations you are solving.

Answer (score 5):

If you need infinite differentiability, then I think a Gaussian is a good choice. For choosing parameters the parameterization given on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function in terms of the width $\sigma$ is easier:

```
g[{μ_, σ_}, x_] = E^(-((x-μ)/σ)^2/2)/(σ*Sqrt[2π]);
dg[{μ_, σ_}, x_] = D[g[{μ, σ}, x], x];
```

Choose $\sigma$ smaller than any feature of your other functions.

Alternatively, if you only need first derivatives you could use a triangle function, this may be even simpler:

```
t[{μ_, σ_}, x_] = Piecewise[{{1/σ (1 + (x - μ)/σ), μ - σ < x < μ},
                             {1/σ (1 - (x - μ)/σ), μ < x < μ + σ}}];
dt[{μ_, σ_}, x_] = D[t[{μ, σ}, x], x];
```

Again, choose the width $\sigma$ smaller than any feature of your other functions.

Usually the Dirac $\delta$-function is defined with $\mu=0$ in the above expressions (it is centered at the origin).

Comment: It is not so simple because  the Gaussian type function tends to the $\delta$-function in the weak topology (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology for info).

Comment: Thanks @user64494, in physics we get lazy about these things, sorry.

Comment: But such an easy approach leads to wrong results in some cases. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function for info.

Comment: @user64494 If the detailed form of your approximation to the delta function matters in a physical calculation, you need to revisit your physics. When we use a delta function, we mean "the impulse is so narrow that its form doesn't matter here". The cases you're worried about are precisely the cases where you shouldn't use a delta in the first place.

Comment: @John Doty: Loking in your questions and answers, I see neither physics nor distributions.

Comment: @user64494: the OP has "PHY" in their username.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a number of approximations. For example, the following three are quite often used.

```
diracDeltaLorentz[x_, eps_] := (eps/Pi)*(1/(x^2 + eps^2))
diracDeltaGauss[x_, eps_] := (1/(eps*Sqrt[Pi]))*Exp[-x^2/eps^2]
diracDeltaSin[x_, eps_] := (1/(Pi))*Sin[x/eps]/x

Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[diracDeltaLorentz[x, i], {i, {1/2, 1, 2}}]], 
 {x, -4, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[diracDeltaGauss[x, i], {i, {1/2, 1, 2}}]], 
  {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[
    Table[diracDeltaSin[x, i], {i, {1/2, 1, 2}}]], 
   {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

Of course, not all definitions are equivalent or well suited for integration with the given function. For example, let’s take

```
d1G = diracDeltaGauss[(x - 
     a*t^2/2) + (1/(2 a))*(v - a*t)^2, ϵ1]
```

and

```
d2G = diracDeltaGauss[(v - a*t) + a*(t - t0), ϵ2]
```

Then you can compute the integrals

```
 xIntDiracDeltaG = 
     Integrate[x*d1G*d2G, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
      Assumptions -> {Element[{a, v, t}, Reals], 
                      ϵ1 > 0, ϵ2 > 0}]

(*Out: 
(E^(-((-a t0 + v)^2/ϵ2^2)) (2 a t - 
   v) v)/(2 a Sqrt[π] ϵ2)
*)
```

and then

```
xvIntDiracDeltaG = 
 Integrate[xIntDiracDeltaG, {v, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {Element[{a, v, t, t0}, Reals], 
                  ϵ1 > 0, ϵ2 > 0}]

 (*Out: a t t0 - (2 a^2 t0^2 + ϵ2^2)/(4 a) *)
```

However if you define similar functions using the definitions of `diracDeltaLorentz` and `diracDeltaSin` above and then try to repeat computation of the same integrals, you will notice that the integrals do not converge. So, the particular choice of a diracDelta "model" depends on the functions you want to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

DSolve can sometimes handle DiracDeltas directly, without resorting to numerical or functional approximations. For example:

```
DSolve[y'[x] + 7 y[x] == DiracDelta[x] + D[DiracDelta[x], x], y[x], x]
```

provides a nice closed form solution.

Comment: It is not so simple. For example, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132453/unsure-solution-of-ode-with-diracdelta-function .

Comment: As other answers suggest, it does depend on the particulars of the ODE.